# Do you still need to file for Paid Family & Medical Leave tax if your company has no employees?

Tags: united-states, taxes, massachusetts

Is a company still responsible for filing PFML taxes if the organization has no employees (in the Commonwealth of Massachusetts)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the state website about the new PFML law](https://www.mass.gov/info-details/whos-a-covered-individual-under-the-pfml-law#remitting-employee-contributions-on-behalf-of-covered-individuals-) (emphasis mine):

> Each quarter, you’re required to remit the required employee contributions for all covered individuals in your MA workforce. **If your MA workforce had fewer than 25 covered individuals, you are not responsible for paying the employer's contribution.**

So it looks like the answer is no, at least for the employer portion. However, depending on how you pay yourself as the owner, your wages [may be subject to the PFML](https://www.mass.gov/info-details/whos-a-covered-individual-under-the-pfml-law#business-owners-and-family-businesses-), and you would need to pay the employee portion.

Additionally, it looks like "covered employees" can include 1099 contractors, so if you hire/employ anyone on a contract basis, you'll need to determine whether they count as a covered employee under the law.